# Best way to work with composer and local modules or packages

Tags: php, testing, composer-php

I'm working on Yii 2 project.

I try to split a project in to packages.

Now I have done with

```
yii2-core that a core that require yii2 base project.
yii2-starter that require core and another packages.
yii2-auth my package
yii2-group my package
yii2-page my package
```

So problem is when I want to implement my packages I do this in my yii2- starter

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "/path/to/the/local/git/repository/group"
    }
],
"require": {
    "my/group": "dev-master"
},
```

That work but I think it not the best way to do this, Because it will have a lot of commit when I coding and testing this packages.

Comment: There is one way to do it with proper IDE setup (not related to composer): create meta-project in it that contains all your sub-packages, register them there as VCS roots and then work with they directly without necessity for constant updates. However, this model will fit the goal only if you're working alone or at most 2-3 people. In distributed teams - only normal flow, but that's the intention of composer.